# I want to use a button when click on active some javascript?

Tags: javascript

The following JS and HTML doesn't work. When I click on the button, it should display only names that have letter a in it. Also, I want to keep the onClick on the javascript side.

```js
var names = ["Lars", "Jan", "Peter", "Bo", "Frederik", "Anna"];

var result = names.filter(function(name) {
  return name.includes("a");

});

document.getElementById("btn").onclick = result;
```

```html
<button id="btn">Get names with letter a</button>
```

Comment: You assign an array to an event handler

Comment: What would you expect this to do? You're not outputting the names in any way anywhere either.

Comment: well im a noop to JS. So i haven't fully understand all the DOM parts yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var names = ["Lars", "Jan", "Peter", "Bo", "Frederik", "Anna"];
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
        var result = names.filter(function (name) {
            return name.includes("a");
        });
        console.log(result)
    });
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Get names with letter a</button>
```

You should filter inside an event listener and the output to the console

Comment: so everything i want to display in HTML should be attached to an eventlistener???

Comment: Im using visual studio. When I'm running the code the button doesn't work?? it's like it can't upload the result.

Comment: Have you checked your console?